# Apiserver in OpenShift

Tags: kubernetes, openshift-origin

I wonder why the Kubernetes apiserver doesn't start when I start OpenShift Origin. Is it possible to start Kubernetes apiserver at OpenShift startup time? And why isn't this the default behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Origin embeds a kubernetes API server by default. The kubernetes APIs are available under the /api and /apis context roots of your origin API server

Comment: Ok, but it doesn't start when I start the master. Why and how can I start it?

Comment: It should be starting - are you using port 8443?

Comment: Yes, but the json response is:
`{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "User \"system:anonymous\" cannot list all nodes in the cluster",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {
    "kind": "nodes"
  },
  "code": 403
}`

Comment: I haven't the rigth permission, now the question is: how I can access kubernetes API from go? :?